# Speedup constrained shuffling. GPU (Tesla K40m), CPU parallel computations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, performance, parallel-processing, shuffle, gpu

I have 100 lamps. They are blinking. I observe them during some time. For each lamp i calculate mean, std and autocorrelation of intervals between blinking.
Now I should resample observed data and keep permutations, where all parameters (mean, std, autocorrelation) are inside some range. Code which I have works good. But it takes to long time (week) for each round of experiment. I do it on computing server with 12 cores and 2 Tesla K40m GPUs (details are in the end).

## My code:

```
close all
clear all
clc
% open parpool skip error if it was opened
try parpool(24); end

% Sample input. It is faked, just for demo.
% Number of "lamps" and number of "blinks" are similar to real.
NLamps = 10^2;
NBlinks = 2*10^2;
Events = cumsum([randg(9,NLamps,NBlinks)],2); % each row - different "lamp"
DurationOfExperiment=Events(:,end).*1.01;

%% MAIN
% Define parameters
nLags=2; % I need to keep autocorrelation with lags 1-2
alpha=[0.01,0.1]; % range of allowed relative deviation from observed 
                  % parameters should be > 0 to avoid generating original
                  % sequence
nPermutations=10^2; % In original code 10^5                  

% Processing of experimental data                  
DurationOfExperiment=num2cell(DurationOfExperiment);
Events=num2cell(Events,2);
Intervals=cellfun(@(x) diff(x),Events,'UniformOutput',false);
observedParams=cellfun(@(x) fGetParameters(x,nLags),Intervals,'UniformOutput',false);
observedParams=cell2mat(observedParams);

% Constrained shuffling. EXPENSIVE PART!!!
while true
    parfor iPermutation=1:nPermutations
        % Shuffle intervals
        shuffledIntervals=cellfun(@(x,y) fPermute(x,y),Intervals,DurationOfExperiment,'UniformOutput',false); 
        % get parameters of shuffled intervals
        shuffledParameters=cellfun(@(x) fGetParameters(x,nLags),shuffledIntervals,'UniformOutput',false);
        shuffledParameters=cell2mat(shuffledParameters);
        % get relative deviation
        delta=abs((shuffledParameters-observedParams)./observedParams);
        % find shuffled Lamps, which are inside alpha range
        MaximumDeviation=max(delta,[] ,2);
        MinimumDeviation=min(delta,[] ,2);
        LampID=find(and(MaximumDeviation<alpha(2),MinimumDeviation>alpha(1)));
        % if shuffling of ANY lamp was succesful, save these Intervals
        if ~isempty(LampID)
            shuffledIntervals=shuffledIntervals(LampID);
            shuffledParameters=shuffledParameters(LampID,:);
            parsave( LampID,shuffledIntervals,shuffledParameters);
            'DONE'
        end
    end
end



%% FUNCTIONS
function [ params ] = fGetParameters( intervals,nLags )
% Calculate [mean,std,autocorrelations with lags from 1 to nLags
    R=nan(1,nLags);
    for lag=1:nLags
            R(lag) = corr(intervals(1:end-lag)',intervals((1+lag):end)','type','Spearman');
    end
    params = [mean(intervals),std(intervals),R];
end
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
function [ Intervals ] = fPermute( Intervals,Duration )
    % Create long shuffled time-series
    Time=cumsum([0,datasample(Intervals,numel(Intervals)*3)]);
    % Keep the same duration
    Time(Time>Duration)=[];
    % Calculate Intervals
    Intervals=diff(Time);
end
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
function parsave( LampID,Intervals,params)
    save([num2str(randi(10^9)),'.mat'],'LampID','Intervals','params')
end
```

## Server specs:

```
>>gpuDevice() 
CUDADevice with properties:

                      Name: 'Tesla K40m'
                     Index: 1
         ComputeCapability: '3.5'
            SupportsDouble: 1
             DriverVersion: 8
            ToolkitVersion: 8
        MaxThreadsPerBlock: 1024
          MaxShmemPerBlock: 49152
        MaxThreadBlockSize: [1024 1024 64]
               MaxGridSize: [2.1475e+09 65535 65535]
                 SIMDWidth: 32
               TotalMemory: 1.1979e+10
           AvailableMemory: 1.1846e+10
       MultiprocessorCount: 15
              ClockRateKHz: 745000
               ComputeMode: 'Default'
      GPUOverlapsTransfers: 1
    KernelExecutionTimeout: 0
          CanMapHostMemory: 1
           DeviceSupported: 1
            DeviceSelected: 1
>> feature('numcores')
MATLAB detected: 12 physical cores.
MATLAB detected: 24 logical cores.
MATLAB was assigned: 24 logical cores by the OS.
MATLAB is using: 12 logical cores.
MATLAB is not using all logical cores because hyper-threading is enabled.

>> system('for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %A in (''wmic cpu get name /value'') do @(echo %A)')
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v2 @ 2.60GHz  
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v2 @ 2.60GHz  

>> memory
Maximum possible array:               496890 MB (5.210e+11 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:      496890 MB (5.210e+11 bytes) *
Memory used by MATLAB:                 18534 MB (1.943e+10 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):                262109 MB (2.748e+11 bytes)

*  Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available.
```

## Question:

**Is it possible to speedup my calculation?** I think about CPU+GPU computing, but I could not understand how to do it (I have no experience with gpuArrays). Moreover, I am not sure it is a good idea. Sometimes some algorithm optimisation gives bigger profit, then parallel computing.

**P.S.**
Saving step is not the bottleneck- it happens once in 10-30 mins in best case.

Comment: Have you profiled your code (on a sub set of data) -> to see exactly (which line(s)) where the time is taken?  Its difficult to really tell how to help without data and/or some profiler stats - however one thing to consider is that simple for loops are *often* faster than cellfun (although I doubt it will reduce order of magnitudes in time....)

Comment: I just use profiler, replacing parfor to just for. I found several point, but their are not so crucial. The question is how to parallelise the process, and may use GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPU-based processing is only available on some functions and with the right cards (if I remember correctly).

For the **GPU** part of your question MATLAB has a [list of available functions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-built-in-functions-on-a-gpu.html) - that you can run on GPU - the most expensive part of your code is the function **`corr`** which unfortunately isn't on the list.

If the profiler isn't highlighting bottlenecks - something weird is going on...  So I ran some tests on your code above:

```
nPermutations = 10^0 iteration takes     ~0.13 seconds
nPermutations = 10^1 iteration takes     ~1.3  seconds
nPermutations = 10^3 iteration takes   ~130    seconds
nPermutations = 10^4  probably takes  ~1300    seconds
nPermutations = 10^5  probably takes ~13000    seconds
```

Which is a lot less than a week...

Did I mention that I put a **`break`** out of your **`while`** statement - as I couldn't see in your code where you ever "break" out of the `while` loop - I hope for your sake that this isn't the reason that your function would run forever....

```
while true
    parfor iPermutation=1:nPermutations
        % Shuffle intervals
        shuffledIntervals=cellfun(@(x,y) fPermute(x,y),Intervals,DurationOfExperiment,'UniformOutput',false); 
        % get parameters of shuffled intervals
        shuffledParameters=cellfun(@(x) fGetParameters(x,nLags),shuffledIntervals,'UniformOutput',false);
        shuffledParameters=cell2mat(shuffledParameters);
        % get relative deviation
        delta=abs((shuffledParameters-observedParams)./observedParams);
        % find shuffled Lamps, which are inside alpha range
        MaximumDeviation=max(delta,[] ,2);
        MinimumDeviation=min(delta,[] ,2);
        LampID=find(and(MaximumDeviation<alpha(2),MinimumDeviation>alpha(1)));
        % if shuffling of ANY lamp was succesful, save these Intervals
        if ~isempty(LampID)
            shuffledIntervals=shuffledIntervals(LampID);
            shuffledParameters=shuffledParameters(LampID,:);
            parsave( LampID,shuffledIntervals,shuffledParameters);
            'DONE'
        end
    end
    break    % You need to break out of the loop at some point
             % otherwise it would run forever....
end
```

Comment: Than You for editing the code! 1) I have conditional break, 2) I present only sample data, in real life I need more than 10^9 permutations to have 1 lamp successfully shuffled.

Comment: You didn't have that information in your question - I can only provide information on what you provide.  For 10^9 permutations - every little bit of performance improvement you will get -> you will get 10^9 times that.